# Aplanar matriz de matrices en una sola con numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Tengo la siguiente situacion:
Una matriz que contiene submatrices

```
lista = [
    [[-5.45886323e-02, -7.84734896e-01],
    [ 3.81139838e-01, -7.22808680e-01],
    [-5.05338192e-01,  8.02502618e-01]],

    [[ 1.34202228, -1.14149842],
    [ 1.14976022,  0.29353322],
    [ 1.11351598,  0.18435089]], 

    [[ 1.34202228, -1.14149842],
    [ 1.14976022,  0.29353322],
    [ 1.11351598,  0.18435089]]]
```

dimensiones:

```
(3,)
```

Y deseo aplanarla de tal forma que solo me quede una matriz de esta manera:

```
rray = ([[-5.45886323e-02, -7.84734896e-01],
    [ 3.81139838e-01, -7.22808680e-01],
    [-5.05338192e-01,  8.02502618e-01],
     
    [ 1.14976022,  0.29353322],
    [ 1.11351598,  0.18435089]
    [ 1.34202228, -1.14149842],
     
    [ 1.14976022,  0.29353322],
    [ 1.11351598,  0.18435089]])
```

He estado intentado:

```
arr1.reshape(Numero_de_filas,2)
```

Lo que me arroja errores tipo No se puede transformar una matriz 3D a 2D

Comment: Revisa el ejemplo que has puesto del resultado deseado. Creo que es erróneo (los corchetes no emparejan) y por tanto no se entiende

Comment: Ya ´puse un ejemplo mas practico, entiendase que cada subista es un arreglo de tipo np.ndarray @abulafia

Comment: Me refería al ejemplo de salida, no al de entrada, de todas formas creo que lo he entendido ya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes es en esencia una secuencia de arrays, por lo que lo puedes pasar como parámetro a `np.concatenate()`. Mira:

```py
from numpy import array

A =array([
   array([[-5.45886323e-02, -7.84734896e-01],
    [ 3.81139838e-01, -7.22808680e-01],
    [-5.05338192e-01,  8.02502618e-01]]),
   array([[ 1.34202228, -1.14149842],
    [ 1.14976022,  0.29353322],
    [ 1.11351598,  0.18435089]]),
   array([[ 1.34202228, -1.14149842],
    [ 1.14976022,  0.29353322],
    [ 1.11351598,  0.18435089]])
])

resultado = np.concatenate(A)
```

Y el resultado es

```
array([[-0.05458863, -0.7847349 ],
       [ 0.38113984, -0.72280868],
       [-0.50533819,  0.80250262],
       [ 1.34202228, -1.14149842],
       [ 1.14976022,  0.29353322],
       [ 1.11351598,  0.18435089],
       [ 1.34202228, -1.14149842],
       [ 1.14976022,  0.29353322],
       [ 1.11351598,  0.18435089]])
```

Comment: Tan sencillo como eso? Llevaba horas intentado varias formas, pense que concantenate siempre recibia dos parametros como lo explican en la documentación

Comment: Recibe  como primer parámetro una secuencia `(a1, a2, ...)` los puntos suspensivos indican que puede tener un número arbitrario de elementos